# Вопрос по работе виджета android

Tags: java, android, android-widgets

[image: Пример]

Пишу виджет часов, на них отображаются значения соответствующие часам (мне они нужны).

Все работает, я разобрался с тем как сделать виджет, как обновлять его каждую секунду, теперь хочу сделать так, чтобы по клику на виджет время останавливалось, а по 2-му клику снова запускалось.

Нашел и разобрался с тем как вообще осуществляется клик по виджету

```
Intent updateIntent = new Intent(ctx, NewAppWidget.class);
updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] { widgetID });
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, widgetID, updateIntent, 0);
widgetView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tvPressUpdate, pIntent);
```

Это обновляет его, не могу разобраться с тем как остановить обновление.
В каком направлении двигаться, вообще не соображу... Может кто подсказать, как лучше организовать паузу?

Код класса ниже.

```
package home.learn.raysclocks;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class RaysClocks extends AppWidgetProvider {

    final String UPDATE_ALL_WIDGETS = "update_all_widgets";
    private static String[] arrsec = {"этнос 10 миллиардов, \nСгусток псевдожизни","этнос 10,\nСгусток жизни", "этнос сто,\nСгусток жизни", "этнос тысяча,\nСгусток жизни", "этнос 10 тысяч,\nСгусток жизни", "этнос 100 тысяч,\nСгусток жизни", "этнос миллион,\nСгусток жизни", "этнос 10 миллионов, \nСгусток жизни", "этнос 100 миллионов, \nСгусток жизни", "этнос миллиард, \nСгусток жизни", "этнос 10 миллиардов,\nСгусток жизни", "этнос 10, \nСгусток информации", "этнос сто, \nСгусток информации", "этнос тысяча, \nСгусток информации", "этнос 10 тысяч, \nСгусток информации", "этнос 100 тысяч,\nСгусток информации", "этнос миллион, \nСгусток информации", "этнос 10 миллионов, \nСгусток информации", "этнос 100 миллионов, \nСгусток информации", "этнос миллиард, \nСгусток информации", "этнос 10 миллиардов,\nСгусток информации", "этнос 10,\nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос сто,\nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос тысяча, \nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос 10 тысяч, \nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос 100 тысяч,\nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос миллион,\nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос 10 миллионов, \nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос 100 миллионов,\nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос миллиард, \nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос 10 миллиардов,\nСгусток ритможизни", "этнос 10, \nСгусток времени", "этнос сто,\nСгусток времени", "этнос тысяча,\nСгусток времени", "этнос 10 тысяч, \nСгусток времени", "этнос 100 тысяч,\nСгусток времени", "этнос миллион, \nСгусток времени", "этнос 10 миллионов, \nСгусток времени", "этнос 100 миллионов,\nСгусток времени", "этнос миллиард,\nСгусток времени", "этнос 10 миллиардов, \nСгусток времени", "этнос 10,\nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос сто, \nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос тысяча,\nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос 10 тысяч, \nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос 100 тысяч,\nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос миллион, \nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос 10 миллионов, \nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос 100 миллионов, \nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос миллиард,\nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос 10 миллиардов, \nСгусток ритмовремени", "этнос 10,\nСгусток псевдожизни", "этнос сто, \nСгусток псевдожизни", "этнос тысяча, \nСгусток псевдожизни", "этнос 10 тысяч, \nСгусток псевдожизни", "этнос 100 тысяч,\nСгусток псевдожизни", "этнос миллион, \nСгусток псевдожизни", "этнос 10 миллионов,\nСгусток псевдожизни", "этнос 100 миллионов,\nСгусток псевдожизни", "этнос миллиард,\nСгусток псевдожизни"};
    private static String[] arrhours = {"Луч Ура", "Луч Ориона", "Луч Пр.центавра", "Луч Южного Креста", "Луч Плеяд", "Луч Земли", "Циклохладавит", "Луч Удя", "Ритмохладавит", "Луч Ири", "Луч выхода", "Радастеид-100", "Луч Яни", "Луч входа", "Луч Радастеи", "Радастеид", "Луч Ара", "Луч Возврата", "Луч Ира", "Луч Человека", "Номерной Хладавит", "Луч Дони", "Луч Б. Медведицы", "Луч Сириуса"};
    private static String[] arrminutes = {"эгрегор рек, родников, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ","эгрегор гор, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор пустынь, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор степей, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор морей океанов, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор равнин \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор лесов  тайги, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор саванны, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор тундры, болот, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор ледников-снегов, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор рек, родников, \nСтруна сердце-пупок", "эгрегор гор, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор пустынь, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор степей, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор морей океанов, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор равнин \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор лесов  тайги, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор саванны, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор тундры, болот, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор ледников-снегов, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор рек, родников, \nСтруна сердце-клубок", "эгрегор гор, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор пустынь, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор степей, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор морей океанов, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор равнин \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор лесов  тайги, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор саванны, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор тундры, болот, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор ледников-снегов, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор рек, родников, \nСтруна сердце-лобок", "эгрегор гор, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор пустынь, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор степей, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор морей океанов, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор равнин \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор лесов  тайги, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор саванны, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор тундры, болот, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор ледников-снегов, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор рек, родников, \nСтруна мозга приказ-показ", "эгрегор гор, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор пустынь, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор степей, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор морей океанов, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор равнин \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор лесов  тайги, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор саванны, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор тундры, болот, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор ледников-снегов, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор рек, родников, \nСтруна мозга рассказ наказ", "эгрегор гор, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ", "эгрегор пустынь, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ", "эгрегор степей, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ", "эгрегор морей океанов, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ", "эгрегор равнин \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ", "эгрегор лесов  тайги, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ", "эгрегор саванны, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ", "эгрегор тундры, болот, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ", "эгрегор ледников-снегов, \nСтруна мозга указ-заказ"};
    private static String[] arrmounts = {"","ЯНВАРЯ", "ФЕВРАЛЯ", "МАРТА", "АПРЕЛЯ", "МАЯ", "ИЮНЯ",
            "ИЮЛЯ", "АВГУСТА", "СЕНТЯБРЯ", "ОКТЯБРЯ", "НОЯБРЯ", "ДЕКАБРЯ"};
    private static String[] arrdayofweek = {"","ПН", "ВТ", "СР", "ЧТ", "ПТ", "СБ",
            "ВС"};




    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "d");
        SimpleDateFormat months = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "M");
//        SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat(
//                "HH");
//
        //Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();



        SimpleDateFormat hours = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "H");
        SimpleDateFormat minutes = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "m");
        SimpleDateFormat seconds = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "s");

        SimpleDateFormat fullhours = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "HH");
        SimpleDateFormat fullminutes = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "mm");
        SimpleDateFormat fullseconds = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "ss");


        CharSequence S = arrsec[Integer.parseInt(seconds.format(now))];
        CharSequence M = arrminutes[Integer.parseInt(minutes.format(now))];
        CharSequence H = arrhours[Integer.parseInt(hours.format(now))];
        CharSequence MN = arrdayofweek[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK]+", "+day.format(now)+" "+ arrmounts[Integer.parseInt(months.format(now))];
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.rays_clocks);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.seconds_value, S);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.minutes_value, M);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.hours_value, H);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.hours, fullhours.format(now));
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.minutes, fullminutes.format(now));
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.seconds, fullseconds.format(now));
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.date, MN);

        Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context, RaysClocks.class);
        updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,
                new int[] { appWidgetId });
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, updateIntent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rl, pIntent);


        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RaysClocks.class);
        intent.setAction(UPDATE_ALL_WIDGETS);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                1000, pIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RaysClocks.class);
        intent.setAction(UPDATE_ALL_WIDGETS);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(UPDATE_ALL_WIDGETS)) {
            ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(
                    context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                    .getInstance(context);
            int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
            for (int appWidgetID : ids) {
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Решил не делать паузу, а просто по клику сохранять значения и каждую секунду выводить из сохранённой переменной до второго клика.

Comment: Так себе решение.

Comment: @Qwertiy Для задачи подошло, не нравится предложите другое.

Comment: Точность портится в такой реализации, потому что таймеры не гарантируют время вызова. А минус не мой, кстати.

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошо, благодарю, отмечу необходимость улучшения, в обновленных версиях.